# Right/Left mouse click on screen in watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

Is there a way to simulate a right/left mouse click at a specific location on screen?

Not `element#click` , but simply specify a location on screen ( 500 , 500 ) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
@browser.execute_script("$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();")
```

**UPDATE**
The trouble is it may not do what you expect from right click

```
@browser.execute_script("$(document.elementFromPoint(2, 2)).trigger({type: 'mousedown', which: 3});")
```

it might be not so much about watir webdriver solution but should work

Comment: Thank you ! Left click works. 
What's the command for right click ?

Comment: what do you expect from right click? what do you need right-click for?

Comment: I have a table which i need to set focus to in order to be able to use `browser.send_keys :space`. The only way i figured to set focus is by clicking one of the rows , but each row is a link so im transfered to another page . 
ive tried `browser.table.focus` but it didnt work as well.

So far the only way i thought of is right mouse click and then left mouse click.